# jQuery OK button in dialog box styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have used jQuery ui dialog box and added an OK button to it and I am using sunny theme. 
The jQuery code is below:

```
$("#error").dialog({
    title: "Error",
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

and styled it using the following css code:-

```
.ui-dialog,.ui-dialog,.ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, 
.ui-corner-all, .ui-draggable, .ui-resizable {
    background:#a8d3f5 !important;
    border-color:#00A2E8 !important;
    color:#FFF;
}​
```

Now everything is set as accordingly as I want except an original border(rectangular) which is around the rounded border(this one gets changed in color) around OK button. Any help with that.

Comment: What does your HTML and jQuery look like?

Comment: Post that in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Also, if you want to style the "OK" button, can't you just style `.ui-button`?

Comment: Its also not working. That ugly border not going.

Comment: Did you try adding `.ui-button {border: none!important; }` after the styles you already have there ?

Comment: @adeneo This also not working

Comment: Use the debugger to see which style is overriding your styles because Bruni's answer is correct with a fiddle proving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
.ui-button { outline: none; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QUyKE/

Or this:

```
.ui-button {
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid red !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QUyKE/1/